# Layout issue in IE- possibly to do with negative margins

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, margin

I'm really struggling with a layout issue in (all versions of) IE. The site I'm working on works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but the layout of the banner is completely wrong in IE, where it appears a few hundred pixels lower than it should. I'm not sure if this is an issue with negative margins or what, and there's not much testing I can do since I'm using a Mac and only have static screenshots to go by.

I'd really appreciate any feedback on this. I've attached an image of what the IE screenshot looks like, and what it should look like. The link to the site is: http://www.osullivans-pubs.com/draft

EDIT: I'm unsure what code to include really since I can't identify the problem but I'm guessing it has something to do with this element:

```
#back {
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 700px;
margin-top: -235px;
padding-top: 80px;
background-position: center -44px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
```

EDIT: I'm attaching an image of the site zoomed out, to give an idea of why negative margins are necessary. It's pretty hard to explain, but it's to do with the diagonal backgrounds and the fact that I need these backgrounds to reach about 1600px (for larger screens, and I can't repeat them, they're diagonal). I wish there were some way to get IE to recognise the negative margins, I've tried the zoom: 1, position: relative technique, but still nothing. Even in IE10.

[image]

[image]

[image: Page zoomed out]

Comment: Post related codes here.

Answer (score 1):

Using negative margins is a bad idea for primary development and should only be used when there is no other solution.

Personally, I consider negative margins a hack.

Position relative will make an element respond relative to its parent, but if you've moved your element outside of its parent with negative margins you can only expect weird results.

In my experience, IE tries to 2nd guess what you want, whereas Mozilla is more wysisyg. so cross browser compatibility will always be a hinderance to you.

If you want your element to always appear in the same place [ relative to pixel position 0,0 (top left)] then use an absolute positionning on the element and specify top and left. this way you can ignore the parent element.

```
#back {
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 700px;
background-position: center -44px;
text-align: center;
position:absolute; top:30px; left:20px; margin:0px; padding:0px;
background-color:red;
}
```

This gets tricky when you want things to reposition themselves based on browser resizing;  So be sure to test the absolute positioning in different situations, full screen, resized, min res, wide screen, screen rotation (if using handheld devices).

Turn off padding and margins completely, while positionning with margin:0px; padding:0px;
and change the background color to something to aide you in seeing edges of your element.
hence why ive added a reg BG on the example above.

Once the element is rougly in the right place (+/- 1 pixel) then you can tweak the margins and paddings.

Comment: That would be a real headache, because they're used a lot in this site. I don't use them them ordinarily but because of the design of this site, where various diagonal background-images had to overlap I resorted to them. I was also under the impression they were completely valid and supported (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/. Repositioning all these elements absolutely would cause layout problems with my grid and would be an absolute nightmare (oops). Pretty stumped now...

Comment: Also, the  background images used in these elements need to cover all of the screen and be centred. If you zoom out on the site you'll see what I mean. I can't do this with absolute positioning.

Comment: hmmm, not making this easy are you :)
Ok, how about floating it inside a parent div container that you can position where you like?
Bit hacky, but should work.
CSS is one of those things thats hard to write a solution for. without getting in there and getting your hands dirty.

Only thing i will say with floats, is, once you start adding them, they tend to be needed all over the place, so be careful.

Comment: I don't think this would be possible with this setup. The image and content element have to be pushed upwards because the (separate) background element covers so much horizontal space. It's really hard to explain what I mean, but with the diagonal backgrounds stretching across and beyond the browser width I need to push elements up, have them work within the grid, and be centred. Is there no way to have IE recognize the negative margins at all? Even IE10 is ignoring them. Every other browser test works perfectly. Very frustrating..

Comment: you could try Firebug for IE. http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite and see where its behaving differently to FF. also, check z-indexes are set on the parent, and give the child a higher index. (shot in the dark)

Comment: Working on a Mac, hence the headache with this. I'll keep fiddling I guess. It's very odd because the negative margins on everything else are working fine. It's just this one element that IE won't recognise.